# getting the right value using MAX() on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

looking TO GET THE MAX() VALUE from a table like the one below. 
Here is what the table looks like

```
LEVEL  ACCOUNTNAME
0.11      namea
1.25      namea
14.55     namea
3.52      namea
```

HER IS THE CODE THAT I USE:

```
SELECT 
MAX(LEVEL) AS HIGHESTLEVEL, ACCOUNTNAME
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ACCOUNTNAME
```

however my returned answer is

```
LEVEL    ACCOUNTNAME
3.52        namea
```

I should be getting 14.55 not 3.52. anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Is your LEVEL a varchar??? 3 > 1.

Comment: Which dbms???  It's the most important thing when asking for question.  You don't want to get answer, but useless because it is for the wrong dbms.  Like the answer below, it will work if you happen to use SQL Server.  But it will not work with other dbms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Level field is a string. Try this in SQL 2012+:

```
SELECT MAX(TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, Level)) AS HIGHESTLEVEL, ACCOUNTNAME
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ACCOUNTNAME
```

This will return NULL for any ACCOUNTNAMEs that don't have any valid numeric values for a given value of LEVEL.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get around the error? it seems that the column may have values that can't be converter to numeric value.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The method could vary.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @OzzyBenitez Then add SQL Server tag to your question.

Comment: Thank you @GarethLyons, unfortunately it did not work i got this error:

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 46
'try_convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: MS sql server 2014

Comment: @OzzyBenitez you can easily search the internet for the equivalent logic to try_convert. But it was introduced with 2012, so either you are using an older version or your db is set to a lower compatibility level.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `TOP` and `DESC`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM TABLE
ORDER BY CAST([Level] as decimal(16,2)) DESC
```

Another way using `MAX` and a `group by`:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST([Level] as decimal(16,2))) AS [Level]
      ,AccountName
  FROM TABLE
GROUP BY AccountName
```

Alternatively, you could change the datatype of [Level] to a decimal or float (which it probably should be, instead of varchar) and your original query would work.